# Verizon Ellipsis Driver Solution

Tags: driver, tablet

After hours of searching, I found like many others that Windows fails to find the driver for my Verizon Ellipsis Tablet. Following the instructions on the support site was no help. Previous forum posts had no solution. My tablet also did not have the drivers on it for ease of install. My solution involves modifying google usb drivers for android to include these devices. I will post the answer as soon as I am allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the Ellipsis Kids but I imagine this will also work for the 7, 8, etc.

Use the official driver if you can find it. Check the support site first.

If you cannot, you may choose to try the following for your own device at your own risk;

1. Install the google android usb drivers (available through android
   sdk manager)
2. Enable usb debugging on your ellipsis if not done so already; Apps >
   Settings > About tablet then tap Build number 7 times
3. I set usb mode on my device to media via the developer menu (these options vary depending on the device you have)
4. In device manager find the errored driver device and open its
   properties
5. In the details tab select hardware id's from the drop down and keep
   this open
6. you should see some id values that may very slightly from what i
   have below; USB\VID_0408&PID_3883&REV_????&MI_00
   USB\VID_0408&PID_3883&MI_00
7. Now navigate to C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver or similar
8. I suggest you make a duplicate of this folder and work within the
   duplicate
9. Edit android_Winusb.inf with notepad or similar
10. I added the following lines under [Google.NTamd64] and also under
     [Google.NTx86];

    ;Ellipsis Kids

    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0408&PID_3883&MI_01
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0408&PID_3883&MI_01
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0408&PID_3883&REV_9999&MI_01
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0408&PID_3883&REV_????&MI_01
11. You'll note that I made different variations of revision and you
     may or may not have to do the same.
12. You will need to use your own device hardware id's above that you
     found earlier (note they can be right click copied)
13. Save the file
14. Then navigate to C:\Users\.android and make a
     backup of adb_usb.ini
15. Edit the original adb_usb.ini with notepad or similar
16. Add the vendor ID 0x408 to the last line in the file
17. Save the file
18. Now just go to update the driver through device manager
19. Point it to the new usb directory you duplicated with the modified
     android_Winusb.inf file
20. Install anyways even though the publisher cannot be verified
21. Violla I can now download my game to the device
22. Once actually attempting to send somethign to your device it will
     request your approval